# Cannot execute bash script in node.js image in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using standard bitbucket pipelines template for CI/CD of React app - CRA.

I have setup `postbuild` step in React App to run simple bash script which just changing file structure in build folder.

in package.json:

```
"postbuild": "postbuild.sh"
```

bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
#  Template React Deploy

#  This template allows you to deploy your React app to an AWS S3 bucket and invalidate the old AWS Cloudfront distribution.
#  The workflow allows running tests, code linting and security scans on feature branches (as well as master).
#  The react app will be validated, deployed to S3 and trigger an AWS Cloudfront distribution invalidation to refresh the CDN caches after the code is merged to master.

# Prerequisites: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY setup in the Deployment variables.
# For advanced cases, please, follow examples from the pipe's:
# README https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-s3-deploy/src/master/README.md
# README https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-cloudfront-invalidate/src/master/README.md

image: node:10.15.3

# Workflow Configuration

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
            # CI=true in default variables for Bitbucket Pipelines https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-in-pipelines/
            - npm test
      - step:
          name: Lint the node package
          script:
            # Run your linter of choice here
            - npm install eslint
            - npx eslint src
          caches:
            - node
  branches:
    master:
      - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            caches:
              - node
            script:
              - npm install
              # CI=true in default variables for Bitbucket Pipelines https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-in-pipelines/
              - npm test
              - chmod +x ./postbuild.sh
              - npm run build
            artifacts:
              - build/**
        - step:
            name: Security Scan
            script:
              # Run a security scan for sensitive data.
              # See more security tools at https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?&category=security
              - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.4.3
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          deployment: Production
          trigger: manual
          clone:
            enabled: false
          script:
            # sync your files to S3
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.4.4
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                S3_BUCKET: 'my-bucket-name'
                LOCAL_PATH: 'build'
            # triggering a distribution invalidation to refresh the CDN caches
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-cloudfront-invalidate:0.1.1
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                DISTRIBUTION_ID: '123xyz'
```

`build` goes fine but later in `postbuild` I am having this error:

```
> @plutora/client@0.1.0 postbuild /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
> postbuild.sh
sh: 1: postbuild.sh: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @plutora/client@0.1.0 postbuild: `postbuild.sh`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @plutora/client@0.1.0 postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-11T12_04_22_330Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I believe bash is irrelevant tag here because error clearly states that can't find `postbuild.sh` which is indeed vendor-specific

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by running the script in `/bin/bash`:

```
...
script:
  - npm install
  - npm test
  - chmod +x ./postbuild.sh
  - npm run build
  - /bin/bash postbuild.sh
...
```

[This](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Can-I-run-own-shell-file-in-pipeline/qaq-p/903576#M33431) helped.

Comment: Literally the problem was that `bash` was not installed! Yet the pipeline kept failing with an error that suggests that the file I was trying to execute did not exist!